# Floating Collector

Tags: power-supply, transistors

I am working on a project where power to the 5VDC supply to a micro can be interrupted during operation (by user). I need to signify to the micro that it is about to lose power so it can perform certain tasks. The image I have provided is generic but gets the point across. My question revolves around  whether or not this design might be harmful to the transistor. I've bread-boarded it and cycled it many times without failure. But I'd like to get further advice. When SW1 opens, K1 will be de-energized causing it's contacts to change state. When this happens the base of the transistor will be energized causing a low input to the micro signifying power will be interrupted. It will perform its tasks. At this point the 5VDC will die out. Therefore the base of the transistor will have ~5VDC, the emitter will be to common (low). At this point, is the collector floating or is it low? if it's floating, will this condition be harmful to the transistor?

I've searched for similar questions here and do not see any.

Any advice would be appreciated.

[image]

Based on all your feedback, I will do the following:
The micro port has analog capabilities. I think I will design to state if port is < 4VDC, power has been interrupted. And then use the schematic below. This is in an attempt to be "nicer" to the micro when power has been interrupted (not including V+)

[image]

Comment: It won't actually be floating because the B-C junction will be forward-biased.

Comment: Why are you not using putting the micro to sleep instead? When the power button is pressed the micro finishes it's current tasks properly and goes into sleep mode when it's ready. No relays. No transistor. No resistors (if you use an internal pull-up).

Comment: I have no choice, power to the 5VDC voltage regulator will be interrupted. The micro will lose it's power supply.

Comment: And how will a relay help you?

Comment: The relay is not something I'm adding. It's part of an existing design. The schematic simply shows it's place in the circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, the voltage you've labeled V+ will remain on, even when +5 disappears.

This is an issue, because current will be able to flow through the base-collector junction of the transistor, and then through the ESD diodes of the micro, trying to power it. It may or may not be enough current to cause damage or turn on the micro, but it's definitely not recommended.

I'd place a diode on the collector to prevent this "reverse" flow.

Comment: A diode wouldn't really help there. Replacing the NPN transistor with an N-Channel MOSFET would be better since there's no junction between the Gate and Drain or Source.

Comment: Or perhaps using a pnp and reversing the logic.

Comment: @brhans Why wouldn't it help? It'll completely block the reverse current flow, assuming OP puts it in the right way.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably going to be ok because the base voltage will be only one diode drop above ground, and the base-collector junction, with the similar voltage drop, will have a small voltage, if any, due to the reverse bias and the current is limited by your base resistor.  However, best practice would be to  consider an opto-isolator here and keep V+ completely separate from +5.